# Android Honeycomb - how to show suggestions for a SearchView when query text is empty?

Tags: android

I've added a SearchView to ActionBar of my application, and setup a SuggestionsProvider using SearchableInfo. Suggestions actually work well, except that no suggestions are shown when search query text is empty. I've found that my suggestion provider is not queried for suggestions even when searchSuggestThreshold is set to 0.

The closest I've come to a solution is to use setOnQueryTextFocusChangeListener and in onFocusChange swap the cursor of SearchView suggestion adapter. This way I see a suggestion drop down of correct height, however no suggestion text is shown.

Here's how I query cursor to show suggestions for empty text.

```
Cursor emptySuggestions = getContentResolver().query(
                            Uri.parse("content://my.authority/search_suggest_query/test"),
                            null, null, null, null);
```

Is there some way to make suggestions appear correctly?

Of course there's always a possibility to show my own ListPopupWindow when search query is empty, but I'd like to avoid that, unless there's an easy way to reuse layout used in SearchView.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out how to trigger search view to query my suggestion provider for empty search text:

```
    _searchView.setOnQueryTextFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener()
        {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus)
            {
            if (!hasFocus)
                return;

            String query = _searchView.getQuery().toString();
            _searchView.setQuery(query, false);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Hi, could you please explain why this works? Why doesn't it work with just the line searchView.setQuery(query,false)?

Comment: @benzabill Actually I don't remember the details and have since refactored the code to no longer need this. I think I had a bug in my SuggestionsProvider.

Comment: Using this solutions suggestions appear behind keyboard. I wrapped code inside "view.post(new Runnable() {". still no use. There must be a handler which norifies if searchview is ready to show suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to manually trigger onQueryTextChange() method above, `SearchView.SearchAutoComplete` threshold need to be set to zero

```
SearchView.SearchAutoComplete sac = (SearchView.SearchAutoComplete) searchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_src_text);
if (sac != null) {
    sac.setThreshold(0);
}
```